# How to properly give Image source for multiple sources?

Tags: c#, unity, sprites

I'm writing a script to change the image on the button based on previous selection.
Another script is giving the `CurrentAvatar` variable once previous button is pressed.

My problem is i can't seem to load an image for the button using:

```
AvatarSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Assets/Images/FireMonsters/Lamor_Icon");
```

Could someone please enlighten me on the proper code?

All from assets, or is it even possible?

Also looking to have multiple options in `if` statements, don't know a better method.

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class SelectedAvatar : MonoBehaviour {

    Button CurrentHeroSprite;
    static Sprite AvatarSprite;
    public static string CurrentAvatar;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        CurrentHeroSprite = GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (CurrentAvatar == "Lamor") {
            AvatarSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Assets/Images/FireMonsters/Lamor_Icon");
            CurrentHeroSprite.image.sprite = AvatarSprite; 
            Debug.Log ("loaded sprite for Lamor");
        }
        //if etc etc etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is Lamor_Icon located in your folder structure? Resources.Load can only be used to load assets that are in a folder called "Resources" (this marks the assets as needing to be serialized for loading on demand from script), and the path you give needs to be relative to that Resources folder.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. The path Assets/Images/FireMonsters/Lamor_Icon looks like the root of your project, rather than inside a Resources folder.

Answer (score 1):

For Resources.Load() to work, your assets must be in a folder called Resources, and this becomes the root of the path. For examples you have a folder in Assets called Resources, which has a folder called sprites and a Sprite called Goblin. You would call:

```
Resources.Load<Sprite>("sprites/Goblin",typeof(Sprite));
```

The files absolutely MUST be nested inside a folder called Resources (which can be anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble linking the sprite in your script, why don't you just assign your script to the sprite itself? Instead of : `Resources.Load<Sprite>("Assets/Images/FireMonsters/Lamor_Icon");` make a generic script, that will `GetComponent<Sprite>` from the sprite you assign it to, add that sprite to your hierarchy, and run your code then?
Or just add the sprite to your scene and instead of using `Resources.Load` you could use `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Resources.Load<Sprite>("Assets/Images/FireMonsters/Lamor_Icon",typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
```

Comment: Why are you casting it twice?